# CBCentralManager run in background but not always, issue oucer when iphone in background mode for long time

Tags: iphone, ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my application I am using Bluetooth LE services. In my application I used `CBCentralManager` and `CBperiperhal` they both working fine in foreground as well as in  background mode, I can connect/disconnect my peripheral to application in both mode.

But, I am facing one big problem in reconnection, When I leave my application in background mode for long time, like one complete night, and in morning when I try to connect my peripheral to my application that time my application is not able find my peripheral not even "`didDiscoverPeripheral`" method get called.

Can any one please suggest me, what I need do for that, So that my application handle this case.

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for this issue? i am facing same issue in one of my project